# Prove that $a_n-10a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=0$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Let $a_n = (5+2\sqrt{6})^n+(5-2\sqrt{6})^n$. Prove that $a_n-10a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=0$.

I think this depends on whether $n$ is even or odd so in the case $n$ is even we have $a_n = 2(\binom{n}{0}5^n+\binom{n}{2}5^{n-2}(2\sqrt{6})^2+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}(2\sqrt{6})^n)$, but it seems computational to do it this way. Is there an easier way?

Comment: it does not depend on odd/even. It is true for the separate  quantities, $(5 + \sqrt {24})^n$ and $(5 - \sqrt {24})^n.$ try those.

Comment: @WillJagy I mean we have to take cases. Also how do we prove it?

Comment: I think you should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it directly:
$$a_n-10a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$
$$=(5+2\sqrt{6})^n+(5-2\sqrt{6})^n-10[(5+2\sqrt{6})^{n-1}+(5-2\sqrt{6})^{n-1}]+(5+2\sqrt{6})^{n-2}+(5-2\sqrt{6})^{n-2}$$
$$=(5+2\sqrt{6})^{n-2}\left([5+2\sqrt{6}]^2-10[5+2\sqrt{6}]+1\right)+(5-2\sqrt{6})^{n-2}\left([5-2\sqrt{6}]^2-10[5-2\sqrt{6}]+1\right)\qquad (1)$$
Now consider the polynomial
$$x^2-10x+1\qquad (2)$$
It has roots
$$x=5\pm2\sqrt{6}$$
And if you look closely, in $(1)$ both $(5+2\sqrt{6})^{n-2}$ and $(5-2\sqrt{6})^{n-2}$ are being multiplied by $(2)$ evaluated at it's roots making their coefficients $0$ and the whole expression $0$.
This is similar to what Jack D'Aurizio mentioned but noticing the theorem in work in this specific case instead of skipping directly to applying the conclusion of said theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: You can solve backward by noting that: $a_0 = 2, a_1 = 10$, then you have $x^2-10x+1 = 0$. What are the roots $r_1, r_2$ for this equation, and then $a_n = Ar_1^n + Br_2^n$. You can solve for $A,B$ and it should match with your formula above.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n = C \alpha^n + D \beta^n $ with $\alpha\neq\beta$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the characteristic polynomial
$$ x^2 - Ux - V$$
that gives $a_{n+2}=U a_{n+1}+ V a_n$. By Viète's theorem, $U=\alpha+\beta$ and $V=-\alpha\beta$.
In our case, $U=10$ and $V=-1$ by straightforward computations.